# Multiple versions of an npm package and import in screens

Tags: react-native

Below this, I tried but Webview is declared duplicate. Error getting.

```
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview-old';
import { WebView as WebViewLatest } from 'react-native-webview-latest';

let WebView;
if (Platform.OS === 'android') WebView = require('react-native-webview-latest').WebView;
else if (Platform.OS === 'ios') WebView = require('react-native-webview-old').WebView;
```

Answer (score 0):

so you problem is you declare `WebView` twice. First in

```
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview-old';
```

and second in

```
let WebView;
```

What you can do is to rename the first import to avoid naming duplicate.

change this:

```
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview-old';
```

to this:

```
import { WebView as WebViewOld } from 'react-native-webview-old';
```